# Buildin blog using Laravel and vue js (code snippet problem)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, code-snippets

I am building a blog post where the author will write an article (including code snippets that the user can copy the code from).
the problem is that when I upload a post with code snippets that has laravel blad[enter image description here][2]e code, it executes and throws an error because the attributes in the code snippets are not defined.

I want to escape executing the code and just view it.

What I have done:
I upload the full article as HTML and store it in the database as it is
I use purifier to make sure that the uploaded code is not malicious
the code snippets are surrounded with `<pre><code></code><pre>`

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

avoid using JavaScript keyword as property name: "class"
  Raw expression: This is code block 1<div class="col">
                    <div class="card ">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Hot Articles
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            @foreach($articles as $a)         
                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                <a href="/articles/{{$a->id}}" class="text-dark font-weight-bold">{{$a->title}}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mt-3 py-2">
                        <img class="d-flex mb-3 mx-auto rounded-circle img-thumbnail" src="/system/Poster.jpeg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="150">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Badr Alwattar</h5>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Fullstack web developer</li>
                                <li>Linux user</li>
                                <li>Freelancer</li>
                            </ul>
                            <h6>Find me online:</h6>
                            <a href="https://instagram.com/badr_alwattar?igshid=1lemoew0gq3bz" target="block"><img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2111/2111463.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"></a>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/iBadr36" target="block"><img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145812.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"></a>
                            <a href="https://github.com/badr-alwattar" target="block"><img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1051/1051326.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"></a>
                            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bader-eddin-alwattar/" target="block"><img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145807.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"></a>
                            <h6>Or send me a message on <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactme">Contact Me</a>, I will be more than happy hearing from you</h6>
                        </div>
                        
                        {{-- <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                          <li class="list-group-item">Drop your message in (Cntact me)</li>
                        </ul> --}}
                        
                      </div>
                </div>Ande this is code block 2

38 |                  <div class="article-body">
39 |                      <img src="/images/1595709974.jpeg" class="img-responsive w-100" alt="Responsive image">
40 |                      <p>This is code block 1&lt;div class="col"&gt;
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
41 |                      &lt;div class="card "&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
42 |                          &lt;div class="card-header"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
43 |                              Hot Articles
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
44 |                          &lt;/div&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
45 |                          &lt;ul class="list-group list-group-flush"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
46 |                              @foreach($articles as $a)         
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
47 |                                  &lt;li class="list-group-item"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
48 |                                  &lt;a href="/articles/{{$a-&gt;id}}" class="text-dark font-weight-bold"&gt;{{$a-&gt;title}}&lt;/a&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
49 |                                  &lt;/li&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
50 |                              @endforeach
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
51 |                          &lt;/ul&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
52 |                      &lt;/div&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
53 |                      &lt;div class="card mt-3 py-2"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
54 |                          &lt;img class="d-flex mb-3 mx-auto rounded-circle img-thumbnail" src="/system/Poster.jpeg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="150"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
55 |                          &lt;div class="card-body"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
56 |                              &lt;h5 class="card-title font-weight-bold"&gt;Badr Alwattar&lt;/h5&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
57 |                              &lt;ul&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
58 |                                  &lt;li&gt;Fullstack web developer&lt;/li&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
59 |                                  &lt;li&gt;Linux user&lt;/li&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
60 |                                  &lt;li&gt;Freelancer&lt;/li&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
61 |                              &lt;/ul&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
62 |                              &lt;h6&gt;Find me online:&lt;/h6&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
63 |                              &lt;a href="https://instagram.com/badr_alwattar?igshid=1lemoew0gq3bz" target="block"&gt;&lt;img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2111/2111463.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
64 |                              &lt;a href="https://twitter.com/iBadr36" target="block"&gt;&lt;img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145812.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
65 |                              &lt;a href="https://github.com/badr-alwattar" target="block"&gt;&lt;img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1051/1051326.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
66 |                              &lt;a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bader-eddin-alwattar/" target="block"&gt;&lt;img class="d-inline mb-3 mx-1" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145807.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="35"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
67 |                              &lt;h6&gt;Or send me a message on &lt;a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactme"&gt;Contact Me&lt;/a&gt;, I will be more than happy hearing from you&lt;/h6&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
68 |                          &lt;/div&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
69 |                          
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
70 |                          {{-- &lt;ul class="list-group list-group-flush"&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
71 |                            &lt;li class="list-group-item"&gt;Drop your message in (Cntact me)&lt;/li&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
72 |                          &lt;/ul&gt; --}}
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
73 |                          
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
74 |                        &lt;/div&gt;
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
75 |                  &lt;/div&gt;Ande this is code block 2</p>
   |  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

(found in <Root>)
```

> code of rendering the body

```php
<div class="col-lg-9">
 <div class="article-body">
  <img src="{{$article->thumbNail}}" class="img-responsive w-100" alt="Responsive image">
  {!! $article->body !!}
                    
  <hr>            
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you show us your code and the error you're getting?

Comment: image link is added, please check it

Comment: Are you able to post that code here, not as a picture but as real code? Same for the error

Comment: question is edited

Comment: Please show use the actual vue/blade template you're using when this error occurs.

Comment: the problem is that it is not in a vue template, I am rendering it in blade.php